# Combining three mysql queries into one json array in php

Tags: php, mysql, json

I have a php script that has three queries that are each returning a set of results.
Now i want to combine the results from the three queries into a single JSON array.

Anyone knows how to achieve this?
The queries can't be joined.

Thanks.

Comment: What are you using to retrieve the data? `mysql_*`, `mysqli_*`, `PDO`...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You might want to look into [`array_merge()`](http://www.php.net/array_merge).

A simple example:

```
<?php
$result = array_merge($array_result_of_query1, $array_result_of_query2, $array_result_of_query3);
echo json_encode($result);
?>
```